# Best Angular extensions/plugins for Modal popup and Tabs

Tags: angularjs

Which is the best Angular extensions/plugins for Modal popup and Tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easy expandable for me and easy-readable sources are provided by [Bootstrap's Black Magic Book](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)